# Inheritance vs composition in keras -- Why is Model inherited from Network

Tags: design-patterns, keras, deep-learning

Hi I am trying to set up my own deep learning framework for my specific domain and [this post](https://blog.keras.io/user-experience-design-for-apis.html) by @fchollet, the author of keras, helped me a lot. However I have a question regarding one specific design decision of keras, that Model is a class inherited from Network.

If I were tasked to design the framework, I would perhaps use Network as one component of Model, instead of the parent class. I understand this is linked to the classic principle of ["composition over inheritance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). I was just wondering why keras chose inheritance over composition in this case. Is this because Network is not used as a component elsewhere? (In other words, Model is the top level abstraction?)

Any comments are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really say "why". This is a low/hidden level decision from the creators.

But I can say that one should never use `Network` objects explicitly when using Keras in a regular way.

We use mainly `Layer`, `Model` and tensors from the respective background. There are other objects we use, but never a `Network`.

So, in order to understand why `Model` derives from `Network`, you need to have deep knowledge of all the hidden source code.